# Accessing Router via HTTPS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssl, dd-wrt

I was trying to access my router's web interface (DD-WRT) page and couldn't get the page to load. Previously, the page loaded with no isue.  I've tried all browsers, and I am only able to access it via HTTP; https used to work fine.  I've tried resetting, and even flashed the newest firmware (11/3/18) and the page still only loads on http.

Before I get too far, I first want to know if HTTPS is needed IF I am only accessing the page on a PC wired to the router and modem.  I never EVER access via wireless.

Error in Firefox: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP 
Error in Chrome: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Comment: What error(s) do you get? Please EDIT the question to add this information.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Which question are you asking; how to get HTTPS working or if using only HTTP is OK? You should not ask both in the same post.

Comment: How to get HTTPS working.  If it isn't needed for wired desktop access, then that can be mentioned as an aside.  I prefer to use https if the solution isn't overly burdensome.

Comment: Those errors suggest the version of DD-WRT you're using is using HTTPS security settings that are really crappy, out of date/obsolete, and probably no longer secure. You may need to upgrade to a modern version of DD-WRT if your version is old, or see if DD-WRT provides a way for you to configure HTTPS settings that don't suck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the certificates on your router are old versions of SSL or use outdated cryptography. Browsers, especially chrome, have been making a push to force this legacy stuff off the internet. Older versions of SSL and crypto are 'broken' and/or do not meet modern security requirements. What has probably happened is that even though you updated your version of dd-wrt, the old certificates have not been changed. These would not be changed as part of an update as they are really part of your configuration. You need to clear these out and regenerate new certificates. There are guides available on the internet that should walk you through this process. Note that chrome has also started to reject self-signed certificates. You will need to go through the "make your own certificate authority" route now for all of the warnings to go away.

To your second question: HTTPS is nice to have, even on the same LAN. HTTPS provides confidentiality, authentication, and integrity on a connection. If we can assure each of these through another method, we do not need HTTPS/SSL. Most of these are at least initially assured because the computer is directly connected to the router. Nobody can get in between and do nasty things to communication with the router. However, there may be some risks due to other machines MAC spoofing and active attacks, so erring on the side of caution the ultimate yes or no is how much you trust the other machines on the LAN. I personally do not trust many of the smart devices and consumer electronics on my LAN. I don't even let them on my LAN; I keep them isolated in a separate network.

Comment: The certificate has no effect on protocol version (which is now TLS not SSL) and almost never on 'cryptography' unless it's missing or entirely unusable in which case _some_ implementations fall back to 'anonymous' suites which browsers don't accept and sometimes manifests as 'no shared cipher'; I don't know ddwrt specifically. Chrome has no problem with a selfsigned cert, but since last year it does reject a cert missing SubjectAltName aka SAN, which real CAs have provided for a decade but most tools used for selfsigned _and_ for DIY CA don't do automatically and sometimes not at all.

Comment: PS: there are numerous existing Qs on both of these (anonymous suites, and selfsigned or DIY adding SAN for Chrome).